# error Overlapped I/O operation is in progress when saving file to server via c#

Tags: c#, wcf, migradoc

I'm creating and saving a pdf document on my server using the pdf Migradoc library  via a c# WCF Service.  Intermittently the filesave will fail and the WCF stack Trace indicates this:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Overlapped I/O operation is in progress'.
>
> at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks) at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher..ctor() at System.Windows.Media.Visual..ctor(ResourceType resourceType) at System.Windows.Media.ContainerVisual..ctor() at PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics..ctor(DrawingContext dc, XSize size, XGraphicsUnit pageUnit, XPageDirection pageDirection) at MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer.PrepareDocument() at MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer.PrepareDocumentRenderer(Boolean prepareCompletely) at MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer.RenderDocument() at SARIService.DigAlertPDF.CreateReport(TicketReport TicketData) at SARIService.ServiceDigAlert.GetDAReportInfo(String ID) at SyncInvokeGetDAReportInfo(Object , Object[]

Once the error occurs it will continue until the server is re-booted or file save attempts need to stop for 15-20 minutes.  Any idea what is happening here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there can be only one `ContainerVisual`. Two threads rendering documents at the same time lead to this error.

After about 20 minutes of idleness, the application domain will be destroyed. Next rendering request will create a new application domain and rendering will work again.

Things you can try:

- Switch to GDI+ build (instead of WPF build) - not sure if that supports concurrent rendering, but it is easy to try it
- Create a new AppDomain for each document, this should avoid the concurrency problem

Comment: Thanks.  I will give this a try

Comment: I am having the same problem with the WPF version (I switched to WPF after I couldn't get GDI to work - I forget what the problem was as this was some time ago). Could you elaborate on how to create a new AppDomain for each document?